# Getting an error CGPathAddPath is unavailable: Use addPath(_:transform) Using Xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, xcode8

Getting an error.

> CGPathAddPath is unavailable: Use addPath(_:transform) Using Xcode 8.0

```
for index in 0...(chars.count - 1) 
{

let letter = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(borderFont, glyphs[index], nil)              

var t = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xPosition , y: 0)

CGPathAddPath(letters, &t, letter)

xPosition = xPosition + advances[index].width

}
```

Comment: You should read [Migrating to Swift 2.3 or Swift 3 from Swift 2.2](https://swift.org/migration-guide/), in particular [SE-0044 - Import as member](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0044-import-as-member.md).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `addPath(_:transform)` like this way.

```
 letters.addPath(letter, transform:t)
```

Check Apple Documentation on [CGMutablePath](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgmutablepath/) for more details.

Comment: its working...thanku:)

Comment: Welcome mate :)